# Displaying values in the table programatically

Tags: sql

In a table TEST, there are columns called A, B. Column A has repeating values 100, 100,100 AS ID of the table and column B should vary according to repeating values in column A. at the first occurrence of value in Column A value in Column B should be 1 but after that it should be 0. IS it possible at the report level rather than changing the values in the physical table. which query can make this possible programmatically at report level?

TABLE

A                B

100     1
100     1
100     1
200     1
200     1
300     1
400     1

EXPECTED OUTPUT

A       B

100        1
100     0
100     0
200     1
200     0
300     1
400     1

Comment: It is possible. Which DBMS? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL.. ?

Comment: What RDBMS (SQL Flavor) do you need it for?

Comment: Do you by any chance have a `unique` ID column in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, here's a solution.

```
select A, 
  case when (row_number() over (partition by A order by A)) = 1
    then 1 
    else 0 
  end as B    
from TEST
```

See [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3552d/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are superb!!!